# How can I run headless (batch) gimp on AWS Lambda function?

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, gimp, gimpfu

I have tried copying the executable and its dependencies but can't seem to perfect that. Do I have another option? I am using python3.

Comment: Is there any kind of useful output that would help others to help you?

Comment: Output from tying to copying everything manually? I don't think that trying to copy the executables and dependencies I need manually is the correct approach, as it seems very hacky. If there is no other approach, I would appreciate some guidance on how to approach that, as the way I was attempting was very sporadic. I also would be interested in recommendations on other options than AWS Lambda that can do something similar but are able to use Gimp batch mode.

Comment: Maybe have a look at http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal and adjust your question accordingly.

Comment: The goal is to run gimp batch mode on many instances of a cloud service (so it will need to be part of the deployment package).

Comment: And what you want to do requires that you use GIMP for this? Unless you plan to work with XCF files, there are usually better suited approaches - ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick, or if you remain closer to the GIMP community, there would be the possibility of using GEGL directly. GIMP hasn't been designed with batch processing on server instances in mind, so we (as in the GIMP developers) are always surprised when people choose to do this. Sometimes this is simply because GIMP has been their one and only venture into application scripting, and this is not a sound base to start from.

Comment: That's correct, the reason that I wanted to go the route of GIMP is familiarity and scriptfus that I have already written. Perhaps the best route would be to take the hit and use ImageMagick, GraphicsMagick, GEGL, or even OpenCV. I appreciate the help.

Comment: I was also interested in this. @MichaelSchumacher is there a way to transpile GIMP script to Imagemagick script?

Comment: None that I know of.